# Using C#, how can I programmatically retrieve and post to the feed that appears on a community site?

Tags: site-template, newsfeed, community

I have created a site using the Community site template.  I want to post to and retrieve the threads that appear on the main page.

I have tried to use the SocialFeedManager class from the client object model to do this, but I haven't found any solutions that work.  If I follow the site and use the GetFeed() method with the 'News' social feed type, the community posts do not appear in my user's newsfeed.  Using the GetFeedFor() method with the site, only appears applicable to a site newsfeed, which isn't defined in the Community template.  I enabled a site feed for the community, but I am still not able to retrieve or modify the posts on the main community page programmatically.

Does anyone know if there is a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are referring to on the Community sites is actually a simple Discussion Board list.  It's not the social newsfeed for a site.  By default, it is a list named "Discussions List".  You can access and interact with that list in C# CSOM like any other SharePoint list.  Start here if you need guidance: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798388.aspx.